# Windows 7 gadgets

Tags: windows-7, windows

Suddenly, the weather gadget has changed. The green and yellow box has disappeared leaving just the temperature and location on the blue desktop.

The clock has vanished. When I drag it from the gadget gallery, nothing appears on the desktop, yet when I look at gadgets running under Sidebar, it says it is running!

All other MS gadgets will drag across normally.

I have disabled the platform, rebooted, re-enabled, rebooted to no avail.

Comment: Upgrade IE lately?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you please change your post to make it clear exactly what your question is?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly there has been a problem with your Windows Updates. Recently, there was an advice from Microsoft itself to disable the gadgets due to vulnerability.

Have a look at your last installed updates, and search for the KB numbers at google (the last 10-15 installed should be enough!), maybe this hotfix has been installed without your agreement.